# boost::asio :: io_service.run() takes long time to return when host details are valid but server side application is not running

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio, tcp

I am new to `network`, `tcp` & `sockets programming`. I am using `boost::asio` in my app to transact data over `wifi` on a `tcp/ip` protocol. The data is sent by *another app that's running on a host machine* whose ip & port is known to my app during start-up. And app connects to this `HostApp` to fetch data at runtime.

**Following is the piece of code in my app which connects to host:**

```
std::shared_ptr<tcp::resolver> resolver = std::make_shared<tcp::resolver>(io_service);
tcp::resolver::query tcp_query(IP_Address, Port_Number);
boost::system::error_code host_resolve_error;
tcp::resolver::iterator destination = resolver->resolve(tcp_query, host_resolve_error);
socket.reset(new tcp::socket(io_service));

if (host_resolve_error) {
    std::cout << "IP & port inputted could not be resolved" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

auto connection_state_callback_handler = [this]
        (const boost::system::error_code& error_code, const tcp::resolver::iterator& it)
{
    if (error_code){
        //Error has occurred. Abort or retry
        connection_set = false;
    }
    else {
      if (it == tcp::resolver::iterator()) {
        //Some logic
        connection_set = false;
      }
      else {
        connection_set = true;
        std::cout << "Callback received for socket connected" << std::endl;

        //Small test to check my data header to confirm that connection is set
        MyDataHeader data_head;
        boost::asio::read(*m_socket, boost::asio::buffer(& data_head, sizeof(data_head)));
    }
  }
};
//call boost asynchronous connect passing it a handler as it needs to report back when ready
boost::asio::async_connect(*m_socket, destination, tcp::resolver::iterator(), connection_state_callback_handler);

io_service.run();  //Takes long time to return when HostApp is not running
StartMyDataThread_WhichPollsData_InALoop();
```

Above code connects quickly & works fine whenever the `ip & port` entered is correct plus the `HostApp` is running. If I enter malformed/irresolvable ip+port then, `host_resolve_error` gets a value & I return out instantaneously. Thanks to the following block.

```
if (host_resolve_error) {
    std::cout << "IP & port inputted could not be resolved" << std::endl;
    return false;
}
```

**But here is the problem I am facing:** When the `ip & port` entered is a valid one plus my `HostApp` is not running on the server side, then `io_service.run()` takes a long time like 20-30 seconds to return. And this is detrimental to my app.

Is there some other API of `io_service` where I can set a `time_out` & get the same functionality as `io_service.run()` ? Or some other way of quickly deciding that my `HostApp` is not running ?

**I tried quite some things to try resolve:**
**1.** I tried to pass `io_service.run()` into `std::async` like below but doesn't work

```
auto handle = std::async(std::launch::async, [this]{ io_service.run( ); });
```

**2.** I tried to call `io_service.run_one()` instead of `io_service.run()`. This one takes time to return as well

***What is the best way to solve this problem ? I need `io_service.run()` to return quickly even if it was not able to set a connection. How do I add a time_out mechanism to `io_service.run()` ?***

Comment: you cannot tell if the target machine is down , the connection has to timeout. The only thing you can do is reduce the timeout

Comment: Agree. But my question is how to add that time_out in this code I put up ?

Comment: Ok. Updated my question. I am looking for a way to add a `time_out` to `io_service.run()`, but I don't know how. Struggling to figure this out

Comment: i do not know boost asio at all, google suggests many things tho http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/async_tcp_client.cpp

Comment: how do I wrap the one line call to `io_service.run()` with a `deadline_timer` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply add the instance of io_service into the deadline timer in the constructor. So import `<boost/asio/deadline_timer.hpp>` and construct your io_service like:

```
client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : stopped_(false),
      socket_(io_service),
      deadline_(io_service),
      heartbeat_timer_(io_service)
  {
  }
```

Then you can call it later in the code like:

```
deadline_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(60));
```

Comment: thanks for your attention. how can I use this `deadline_.expires_from_now` with `io_service.run`. Call it just before calling `io_service.run` ?

Comment: As I understand, I pass this `deadline_` into `async_connect` function only. Not into `io_service.run`.

Comment: Yes if you do async. You can also do a blocking connection.

Comment: I called io_service.run in std::async. That solved the problem. I am thinking I should post this version of answer as well using async